# how to filter Google places result with zipcode

Tags: android, google-places-api

I'm trying to fetch the address within the zip code provided, But it does not have any way to do that.

```
AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
                .setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_ADDRESS)
                .setCountry(Constants.COUNTRY)
                .build();
        autocompleteFragment.setFilter(typeFilter);

        autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Status status) {
                showErrorMessage(R.string.error_title_msg, status.toString(), null);
            }
        });
```

The AutocompleteFilter has only param like setContry, is there a way to pass zipcode to the filter ?

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is to use setBoundsBias:

```
autocompleteFragment.setBoundsBias(new LatLngBounds(
    new LatLng(-33.880490, 151.184363),
    new LatLng(-33.858754, 151.229596)));
```

But isn't the best solution of course as you need to get coords for each zip and set some bounds.

Comment: yes i'm searching for better solution as everytime getting coordinates is not feasible